# removing elements incrementally from a list

Tags: python, list

I've a list of float numbers and I would like to delete incrementally
a set of elements in a given range of indexes, sth. like:

```
for j in range(beginIndex, endIndex+1):
   print ("remove [%d] => val: %g" % (j, myList[j]))
   del myList[j]
```

However, since I'm iterating over the same list, the indexes (range)
are not valid any more for the new list.
Does anybody has some suggestions on how to delete the elements
properly?

Best wishes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you really need to remove them incrementaly?

If not, you can do it like this:

```
del myList[beginIndex:endIndex+1]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate from the end to beginning of the sequence:

```
for j in range(endIndex, beginIndex-1, -1):
    print ("remove [%d] => val: %g" % (j, myList[j]))
    del myList[j]
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
>>> list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> start, end = 2, 4
>>> list1[:start] + list1[end:]
[1, 2, 5, 6]
```